# Need advice on using XML as database C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I am making an application that stores data that user inputs.

http://i827.photobucket.com/albums/zz200/ArnasG/question_in_stackowerflow__zps4f7uy3l7.png

I have a bit of an issue because of my lack of experience, I want to save all the data user inputs in XML file and to load it when program starts next time. I had an idea to use dataset to read all the data from XML file and then work with the table[0] of that dataset(add/delete rows). It turn out that I can not make it to work properly. It loads some blank lines and lines that I created in previous tries, but there is only two lines that are actually saved in XML file.  How could I make this work?

Thank you for your time :)

Actual XML file:

http://i827.photobucket.com/albums/zz200/ArnasG/question_in_stackowerflow_V2_zpshmwjnllr.png

```
DataSet ListOfTrades = new DataSet();
DataTable Lentele = new DataTable();
ListOfTrades.Tables.Add(Lentele);


    // adding columns to the table

    try
    {

            DataColumn Pair = new DataColumn("Pair", typeof(string));
            Pair.AllowDBNull = false;
            DataColumn Entry = new DataColumn("Entry", typeof(string));
            Entry.AllowDBNull = false;
            DataColumn StopLoss = new DataColumn("StopLoss", typeof(string));
            StopLoss.AllowDBNull = false;
            DataColumn TakeProfit = new DataColumn("TakeProfit", typeof(string));
            TakeProfit.AllowDBNull = false;
            DataColumn TakeProfit1 = new DataColumn("TakeProfit1", typeof(string));
            TakeProfit1.AllowDBNull = false;
            DataColumn TakeProfit2 = new DataColumn("TakeProfit2", typeof(string));
            TakeProfit2.AllowDBNull = false;
            DataColumn TakeProfit3 = new DataColumn("TakeProfit3", typeof(string));
            TakeProfit3.AllowDBNull = false;
            DataColumn LongShort = new DataColumn("LongShort", typeof(string));
            LongShort.AllowDBNull = false;
            DataColumn WinLoss = new DataColumn("WinLoss", typeof(string));
            WinLoss.AllowDBNull = false;

            data.Tables[0].Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
        Pair, Entry, StopLoss, TakeProfit, TakeProfit1, TakeProfit2,
        TakeProfit3, LongShort, WinLoss
        });
        }

    catch(Exception Ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
    }

 // Adding new line to the table after user clicks save button

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow eilute = ListOfTrades.Tables[0].NewRow();
        eilute[0] = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
        eilute[1] = textBox1.Text.ToString();
        eilute[2] = textBox2.Text.ToString();
        eilute[3] = textBox3.Text.ToString();
        eilute[4] = textBox4.Text.ToString();
        eilute[5] = textBox5.Text.ToString();
        eilute[6] = textBox6.Text.ToString();
        if (radioButton1.Checked) { eilute[7] = "Long"; }
        else { eilute[7] = "short"; }
        if (radioButton1.Checked) { eilute[8] = "Win"; }
        else { eilute[8] = "Loss"; }

        ListOfTrades.Tables[0].Rows.Add(eilute);
        ListOfTrades.Tables[0].WriteXml(DefaultPathToJournalXML);

        dataGridView1.Update();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();

    }
```

Comment: Don't write blank lines into XML, then you don't have to worry about reading the blanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not getting duplicated.  here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
   <Table1>
      <Pair>AUD/USD</Pair>
      <Entry>0.00000</Entry>
      <StopLoss>0.00000</StopLoss>
      <TakeProfit>0.00000</TakeProfit>
      <TakeProfit1>0.00000</TakeProfit1>
      <TakeProfit2>0.00000</TakeProfit2>
      <TakeProfit3>0.00000</TakeProfit3>
      <LongShort>short</LongShort>
      <WinLoss>loss</WinLoss>
   </Table1>
   <Table1>
      <Pair>AUD/USD</Pair>
      <Entry>0.00000</Entry>
      <StopLoss>0.00000</StopLoss>
      <TakeProfit>0.00000</TakeProfit>
      <TakeProfit1>0.00000</TakeProfit1>
      <TakeProfit2>0.00000</TakeProfit2>
      <TakeProfit3>0.00000</TakeProfit3>
      <LongShort>short</LongShort>
      <WinLoss>Loss</WinLoss>
   </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
​
```

Here is code

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(FILENAME);
        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Think object oriented, and think [Linq.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508450/how-do-i-use-linq-to-xml-to-create-a-list-of-objects)

For example, let's say you have this XML file:

```
<trades>
    <trade>
        <pair>some pair</pair>
        <stop-loss>stop loss 1</stop-loss>
    </trade>
    <trade>
        <pair>other pair</pair>
        <stop-loss>stop loss 2</stop-loss>
    </trade>
</trades>
```

You can create a Trade class to hold the data in the trade tags and then use a Linq query to populate the object given the XML file:

```
class Trade
{
    public string Pair;
    public string StopLoss;
    // Other variables from trade tag would go here...

    // Function that can load trade objects from XML file into a list of Trade objects (List<Trade>)
    public static List<Trade> loadTrade(string xmlFilePath)
    {
        // Load your XML document given the path to the .xml file
        var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);

        // For each trade element in the trades element
        var trades = (from trade in doc.Element("trades").Elements("trade")
                      select new Trade
                      {
                          // For each element in the trade element, put value in class variable
                          Pair = trade.Element("pair").Value,
                          StopLoss = trade.Element("stop-loss").Value
                      }).ToList<Trade>();

        return trades;
    }
}
```

When you're ready to save to a file you basically do the opposite of the Linq query to create an XML file. It will look very similar.

On there other hand, read [this article](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163082/using-xml-as-data-storage) and consider if there's a better alternative.